# ¿Cómo dejar una vista al frente de un bottom sheet?

Tags: android, material-design

En mi activity principal tengo un botón que está ubicado en la parte inferior. Ahora, cuando llamo al *bottom sheep*, esté mismo oculta por defecto a este botón ya que está por encima, y no quiero que sea así. Es decir, lo que estoy buscando es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi código actualmente, solo estoy llamando al archivo que contiene mi *Bottom Sheet*

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
bottomSheet.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_sheet);
bottomSheet.show();
```

Pensé en darle una translationZ como lo siguiente pero no funciono.

```
android:id="@+id/btnBottomSheep"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:translationZ="90dp"
```

Cualquier respuesta se agradece.

Comment: se supone que el bottom sheet debe ir encima de todo. Lo que puedes hacer es colocar dentro de él otro botón con la misma funcionalidad.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Yo tambien pense lo mismo pero viendo una conocida aplicación para aprender idiomas, ví que está haciendo lo que yo quiero hacer. Aca esta el ejemplo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fzo6RRHMU46pmjvzDW82sL4lTfQbEbZR/view?usp=sharing